# Android - How can I access a View object instantiated in onCreate in onResume?

Tags: java, android, view

In my `onCreate()` method, I'm instantiating an `ImageButton` View:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_post);

    final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
...
```

In `onResume`, I want to be able to change the properties of the `ImageButton` with something like:

```java
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ib.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
}
```

But `onResume` doesn't have access to the `ib ImageButton` object.  If this were a variable, I'd simple make it a class variable, but Android does not allow you to define View object in the class.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You can't use findViewById inside of onResume?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make the image button an instance variable, then you can refer to it from both methods if you like. ie. do something like this:

```
private ImageButton mImageButton = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.d(AntengoApplication.LOG_TAG, "BrowsePicture onCreate");
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.layout_post);

  mImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
  //do something with mImageButton
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  mImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
  mImageButton.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
}
```

It's worth bearing in mind though that instance variables are relatively expensive in Android, so it's more efficient to use a local variable within the method if it's only used in one place.

Comment: Yes, this worked.  I had incorrectly thought that this would not work in Android since I kept getting a force close before onCreate.  Turns out, my error was that I had:
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_image);

and that leading "ImageButton" was the culprit.  Thx.

Comment: Why are instance variables are relatively expensive in Android. I hear of it for the first time, Performance Tips (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) do not mention it...

Answer (score 3):

`findViewById()` does not create the view, it is just finding the already created view.  It was created by inflating the layout `R.layout.layout_post` in the previous line.

You could simply call `findViewById()` in your `onResume()` method to get a reference to it in that method, or you could change `ib` to an instance variable so that it is accessible in methods other than `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration from the method to the class. Assuming `selectedImageUri` is within scope...

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {
    ImageButton ib;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(AntengoApplication.LOG_TAG, "BrowsePicture onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_post);

        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ib.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }
}
```