# NullPointerException checkbox sharedpreferences

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the values from different checkboxes located in a layout.xml file, using sharedpreferences.

But when i compile the program i get a NullPointerException, according Logcat the cause is in line 463, marked in my code.

I tried sevaral things, but i can`t get rid of the exception.

Could someone please help me?

The Exception from Logcat:

```
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.sencide/com.sencide.AndroidLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1789) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.sencide.AndroidLogin.onResume(AndroidLogin.java:463) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231) 
10-29 23:35:31.556: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     ... 12 more
```

Part of the code in my Main program xml:

On Create and set values:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPrefsDemoPreferences"; 
public static final String PREF_BOOL = "PrefBool";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private CheckBox mCheckBox;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    mCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel);// in layout.xml
```

The OnPause and OnResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {      
    mCheckBox.setChecked(mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_BOOL, false)); <-- Line 463   
    super.onResume();}

@Override    
protected void onPause() { 
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    e.putBoolean(PREF_BOOL, mCheckBox.isChecked());              
    e.commit();         
    Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    super.onPause();    }
```

The layout file with the checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/nieuwbel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Nieuw beltegoed" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/vorige"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Tegoed vorige periode" />
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `SharedPreferences` again. At that point `mPrefs` can be also null object. Also try reinstatiating the `mCheckBox`. This happens if the activity went from `onPause()` to `onResume()` not calling `onCreate()` again where you have instatiation of both object properly.

Edit:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {      
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         mCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel);
        if(mPrefs!=null)  //check in case there are no prefs saved, due some reason
           mCheckBox.setChecked(mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_BOOL, false));
        else
            mCheckBox.setChecked(true); //here put default value if there are no preferences saved
        super.onResume();
}
```

Edit 2: Inflating the other xml.

You put this inside onResume()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null); // you have the xml as a view from which you can extract the checkbox
   mCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel);
   .... do the rest of the coding in the first edit :)
```

Comment: Hi Nikola,
Thx for replying, would you mind to give me some correction code for this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Nikola,
Thx for the new code, i applied it but i am still getting the NullException on line 465 what would be: mCheckBox.setChecked(mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_BOOL, false));
Tough not to crack i suppose.

Comment: Is the ID of the checkbox correct? Seems that mPrefs is not null. So the mCheckBox is definitely null.

Comment: The checkbox is located in another xml file called layout.
It should be ok.
mCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); // in layout xml
I`m struggling with this for some days now but i can`t get the solution.
I include the code for the layout file, maybe it helps.
Would be great if you could be of assistance.

Comment: Owww...thats another problem. If the checkbox is located in another layout (another xml) then you need to inflated that XML...I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: Ok almost there.
The app runs without exception but the checkboxe values are not remembered.
I set the checkboxes in the layout file to android:checked="true"
Could that be the problem?

Comment: It`s not saving the values but i`ll except your answer anyhow.
Thx Nikola.

Comment: Make sure at the point where you save the prefs the mCheckBox is not null and then just save .isChecked() output  :)

Comment: Hmmm, i am lost now.
If i uncheck a checkbox in the layoutfile, a onClickListner is implements like this: CheckBox niewbel = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); 
         readyListener.ready(niewbel.isChecked());
Do i have to set something in this, to get it saved?

Comment: By saving i meant saving it in the preferences. In your case you are saving the preferences in the onPause(), so you dont have to save it every time there is changes in the checkbox (going in checked/unchecked).

Comment: Hi Nikola,
Hope youre well :)
I still can`t get it to work, realy frustrating after 6 hours still no improvement.
I realy don`t know where to search the error anymore.
If i click the Ok button on the layout xml with the checkboxes, i`ll to pass the checkboxes.checked or not?

Comment: Hi Nikola,
Don`t have twitter, chat maybe?
Can you create a room?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4598/discussion-between-nikola-despotoski-and-lars)


Come over @Lars

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips:

1) Make sure you check it isn't null straight after you find it.

```
mCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel);
Toast.makeText(this, "Is checkbox null? " + mCheckBox, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

2) Separate out the line with the `NullPointerException` so you know which variable is null.

```
boolean savedValue = mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_BOOL, false);
mCheckBox.setChecked(savedValue);
```

If mPrefs is null then you probably need to get the SharedPreferences again.

```
mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```