# NullPointerException when activity starts and checkbox is not checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement the following code:

```
 public CheckBox checkboxer() {
    final CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "make ListView clickable");
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {              
            box.setChecked(true);
        }
    });       
    return box;
}

   private void savebox(final boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "checkbox is saved");
}

private boolean load() { 
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", false);}
```

When I save it

```
onPause(){
     savebox(checkboxer().isChecked());
}
```

Log indicates that it is saved.
Bun when I put

```
onResume(){
     checkboxer().setChecked(load());
}
```

comes `NullPointerException`.

I think it is because nothing is checked and saved when activity starts running. Am I correct? How can I go around?

Thank you very much.
here we go

**Logcat:**

```
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {example.CustomAdapter/example.CustomAdapter.ChildActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at example.CustomAdapter.ChildActivity.onResume(ChildActivity.java:256)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08:18:37.830    1773    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 12 more
```

Sorry, I forgot. Could it be because in my adapter class I have View method with

```
 CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);

    cbBuy.setTag(position);

    cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
    return view;`
```

And also

```
  OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

      getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
    }
  };
```

Sorry I am a new guy and probably don't understand what kind of condradiction could be between checkbox declaration in adapter and in activity. If it is caused because of such contradiciton please explain.

Here is the exact coding for `onResume` and `onPause`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ChildActivity: onResume()");
    DataSourceChild.openToWriteChild();
    checkboxer();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ChildActivity: onPause()");

    DataSourceChild.closeChild();

    savebox(checkboxer().isChecked());

}
```

The whole code is too big. Let me provide you with onCreate first`    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.child);

```
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ChildActivity: onCreate()");

    child_datasource = new DataSourceChild(this);
    DataSourceChild.openToWriteChild();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    val_position = intent.getIntExtra("value_1", pos_1);
    val_id = intent.getLongExtra("value_2", pos_2);

    onSelectionMade();

}


public void onSelectionMade() {

    if (val_position == val_id) {

        loader(val_position);
    }
}`
```

The loader contains checkboxer and looks as follow` public void loader(int val) {

```
    item_values = child_datasource.readItem(val);

    // определяем адаптер
    boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, item_values);

    // настраиваем список
    lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    // выставляем адаптер
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

    // регистратор контекстного меню
    registerForContextMenu(lvMain);

    // метод для работы с checkbox
    checkboxer();

    boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}`
```

Now in custom BoxAdapter I have the following

```
`  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);

    cbBuy.setTag(position);

    cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
    return view;
  }`
```

Sorry for inconvenience caused. But I want to find out what is going on.

Your sample works with one click. Thank you very much. I have tried to update my adapter View method in the following way

```
`  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    cbBuy.setTag(position);

    cbBuy.setChecked(mIsChecked[position]);

    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

      mIsChecked[position] = isChecked;
      getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
    }
  });

    return view;
  }
  `
```

and made change in onCreate

```
 `    public void loader(int val) {

        item_values = child_datasource.readItem(val);

        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

        boolean[] isChecked = new boolean[item_values.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < item_values.size(); i++) {
            isChecked[i] = false;
        }

        boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, item_values, isChecked);

        lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(lvMain);

        boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`
```

it still can not save checks when I leave ChildActivity. I am sad that I can not apply your example and my knoweledge of Android is not enough for operating with View so easy as you do it. If you can further explain me how should I change View to get result I will appreciate it, if no then sorry for your time.

Comment: What did your debugger say about the null pointer?

Comment: just a guess...you can declare the Checkbox box as a class member and then initialize it in onCreate() as box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

Comment: I moved checkbox to method with purpose to avoid nullpointer

Comment: Post us the code for this line: at example.CustomAdapter.ChildActivity.onResume(ChildActivity.java:256)

Comment: checkboxer().setChecked(load());

Comment: Are you sure lvMain from checkboxer() method is not null?

Comment: to move checkboxer().setChecked(load()); to on Create did not work

Comment: Debug through onto onResume and see if checkbox is null or lvmain is null, then we can narrow it down. Just watch both variables and see if lvMain is null. If it is then the list is not being found

Comment: don't forget to call super.onResume(); + could it be that you have not set your contentview?

Comment: Also call super.onResume() and super.onPause() from your methods

Comment: lvMain could not be null because when i run resume checkboxer() it works and checkboxer() is present in onPause

Comment: A similar one here - see if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942743/nullpointerexception-checkbox-sharedpreferences

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It makes sense. Let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the activity is started onResume() will be called. So in onResume() just give a check before calling setChecked function so that it should execute only when checkboxer() is not null to ensure it being executed only when the activity is resumed.

```
onResume(){
     if(checkboxer() != null)
          checkboxer().setChecked(load());
}
```

Sample activity with checkbox and listview

```
package com.example.checkdoubltap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CheckLayoutParams extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lin);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    boolean[] isChecked = new boolean[countryStrings.length];
    for(int i=0;i<countryStrings.length; i++){
        isChecked[i] = false;
    }
    CheckBoxAdapter adapter = new CheckBoxAdapter(CheckLayoutParams.this, countryStrings, isChecked);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private String[] countryStrings = { "Afghanistan", "Albania",
        "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ascension Island", "Australia",
        "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
        "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda",
        "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana",
        };
}
```

Sample adapter:

```
package com.example.checkdoubltap;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.CompoundButton;
  import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

  public class CheckBoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private String[] mCountries;
private boolean[] mIsChecked;

public CheckBoxAdapter(Context context, String[] countryStrings, boolean[] isChecked) {
    mContext = context;
    mCountries = countryStrings;
    mIsChecked = isChecked;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(mCountries != null)
        return mCountries.length;
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CheckBox view = new CheckBox(mContext);
    view.setChecked(load(position));
//  view.setChecked(mIsChecked[position]);
    view.setText(mCountries[position]);
    view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("Check","Changing position to"+position+" "+isChecked);
            mIsChecked[position] = isChecked;
            savebox(position,isChecked);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private boolean load(int position) { 
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ((Activity) mContext).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(""+position, false);
}



private void savebox(int position, final boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ((Activity) mContext).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(""+position, isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "checkbox is saved");
}
  }
```

Layout with listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/listview"
>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is what I thought as well. It runs but it does not save when chekboxes are checked

Comment: you have savebox function in onPause right? is that functioning properly? in that case in onResume it should setCheck properly

Comment: I can only guess that it functions properly because of  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "checkbox is saved"); at the end of safebox method

Comment: And when I run code without onResume{checkboxer().setChecked(load())} it shows me Log

Comment: Could you please see my edited question. May be problem caused by my adapter.

Comment: u have a listview with eachrow containing a checkbox?

Comment: Yes,I have a listview with eachrow containing a checkbox

Comment: in that case, can you reedit your question to include the whole activity and the getView of the adapter u r using.. The snippets above are a bit confusing

Comment: Please see above edited. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18623/discussion-between-user936414-and-user1706819)