# Android ListView losing item height

Tags: android, listview

So I have a lisview where each row/item hides/shows different controls.

I keep track of all data and set visibilty of controls in **onItemClick** and **getView** depending on my data.

However, this means the height of the items are different... But when a user scrolls an item out-of-view that has nonstandard height, its height gets reset to standard even though its controls visiblity is set in **getView**

What to do? Is there a way to force recalculate height?

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;

                if(null == view)
                {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) thisActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.override_listitem_catalog, null);
                }

               MyListItemExt data = objects.get(position);


                if(null != data)
                {
                                            // ... do work
                }
```

Comment: the problem may be because of convertview. Post your code

Comment: I will try without " if(null == view)", not sure why you need that..performance reasons?

Comment: where are the widgets which their heights are changed?

Comment: how exactly do you update the visibility of the views? did you remember to update the data before you update the visibility ? did you try (just temporarily) to use only notifyDatasetChanged for the onItemClick  ? what is exactly the "scrolling of out-of-view" ? can you somehow show a screenshot or a sketch to what you mean here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are hiding and showing widgets, rather than using dedicated row layouts for each different type of data, then using `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare The reason was that the amount of text (if any) + image size (if any image) would differ row to row. (Like text filling entire screen for some items)

Comment: For what it is worth, problem appeared to be related to the image somehow. I solved it by fixing the imageview width in code to screen width (instead of "wrap-content" and/or parent view width - earlier code used OnGlobalLayoutListener) + SetDrawable instead of SetImageBitmap. Those two thing combines solved multiple odd listview item size problems. It works now for whatever odd reason. More details available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621816/listview-changing-size-of-reused-views (I encountered what was the same problem for two different listviews I were coding and designing)

Answer (score 1):

When scrolling the listview, the scrolled rows is reused and filled with the new data. According to your logic, when you set the visibility of buttons onclick of a list item row, the state of this row will not be maintained when you scroll the list and come to this position again as the views are being reused.

You have to keep the clicked positions of the listview in a hashmap or a boolean array(if the number of items in the list is less) making the position index to true. In getView, check if the position is already clicked with the boolean array value. If true, then make the buttons visible. Else make them invisible. For a clear idea on how to use them check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13083795/936414

Comment: As I wrote in my initial post, I am keeping track of visibility in my own data structure (**data** reference in code) and setting visibility of controls every time in the **getView** code. That works as far as I can tell, the **height** however does not :(