# Listview changing size of (reused) views

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I am all for reusing views in listview. I always set visibility, contents, witdth etc. of *all controls* again in **getView** Unfortunately it seems ListView fails to recalculate height.

Picture one shows the initial item showed:
[image]

Picture two shows how item one is rendered after we scrolled away and back into it
[image]

The background linearlayout height (the black area) **made me** think that in picture two, Android is reusing a view that just showed a much heigher item (e.g. the second item). But why does it not recalibrate/reset/recalclulate itself (it is in "wrap_content" mode in its XML) when reused as view for the first item which content (text + image) is not as heigh?

In truth I am not sure what is happening. The problem only manifests itself if I have image in the view. I have tried organize the bitmap/image loading in different ways (sample code underneath) with different things commented out, but that does not seem to make much difference. I am really at a loss here as to the reason.

**override_listitem_news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
 android:background="@android:color/black"        
        >                           
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_news_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="@string/newsItemTitle"/>           
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_news_date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="@string/newsItemDate"/>                   
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_news_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text="@string/newsItemDesc"                    
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"                
                />                    
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_news_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                                   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
    />        
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code where I load image in **getView**

```
                        ViewTreeObserver vto = image.getViewTreeObserver();
                        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                          new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                              image.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);                                                                 
                              image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                              SharedCode.sharedUtilScaleImage_Width(image);                                      
                            }
                          }                        
                        );                                                                   

                        image.setTag(data.image_file_name + data.image_file_url);
                        Bitmap bit = null;
                        bit = SharedCode.sharedGetFileFromOffline(thisActivityContext, "news", data.image_file_name, MyGetKindOfFile.ImageAsBitmap).bitmap;

                        if (bit != null) {                                                                       
                          image.setImageBitmap(bit);                                                                                                                                                      
                          image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                  
                        }
                        else {
                          image.setImageBitmap(null);                                  
                          image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                       image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                                                                               
                       image.setBackgroundColor(data.backgroundColorInt);
```

Comment: post the xml layout for your item view.

Comment: Are you overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in your adapter?

Comment: No, only **getView** **getCount** **getItem** **getItemId**

Comment: I have added some more code (where I load  image/bitmap since problem only seems to manifest itself if the item/view contains an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, problem appeared to be related to the imageview. Just for reference, I will write here how I solved it.

1. In **getView** I fixed the imageview width to screen width (instead of "wrap-content" and/or parent view width - earlier code used OnGlobalLayoutListener for parent width)
2. I switched over to using SetDrawable instead of SetImageBitmap. It is odd, but this difference was actual very important in solving the odd space around the imageview after scrolling an item/row in/out of view.

My research did also indicate that others had problems using wrap_content in listview for cases similar to mine, but I was not able to find anyone who had experienced exact same problems as me.